# how do i add in retrofil one array of array ? & Android get request

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i'dl like to know how i can send some params like:
I know that @Query can send list. But how can i send this list in ?

```
itemList=
[
    {   "MenuItemId":"825aa3a5-42f6-4a4f-b396-8ab94de23752"   , "Quantity":3 },
    {   "MenuItemId":"dd3973c4-db28-44ab-ad92-40e978608e89"   , "Quantity":2 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use '@QueryMap' to send the list of parameter as hashmap.
Here is the refernce [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).